# How do I incorporate a timestamp column into a query that already uses and aggregate function?

Tags: sql, timestamp, aggregate

I have a  sql database called textbankvendor.messages_export of all messages sent from an organization that does text campaigns.

The relevant columns in this database that I am using are the following below:

activity_title (varchar): the name of a textbank that an individual message belongs to

message_segments (integer): the number of segments (a segment is a grouping of 160 characters) in a message

activity_published_at (timestamp): the date that the textbank was published

So an example of a couple rows in the database would be:

| activity_title | message_segments | activity published at |
| --- | --- | --- |
| March Outreach Textbank | 3 | 2021-03-18 20:32:00.045294 |
| April Outreach Texbank | 4 | 2021-04-22 18:27:00.045294 |
| March Outreach Textbank | 3 | 2021-03-18 20:32:00.045294 |
| April Outreach Textbank | 4 | 2021-04-22 18:27:00.045294 |

My goal is to output all the unique texts banks in the data base along with the total message segments sent for all messages in that text bank and the date the textbank was published. Using the above example the goal would be this:

| activity_title | cumulative_message_segments | activity published at |
| --- | --- | --- |
| March Outreach Textbank | 6 | 2021-03-18 20:32:00.045294 |
| April Outreach Texbank | 8 | 2021-04-22 18:27:00.045294 |

I was able to successfully use the below query to get the activity title and the number of message segments:

```
SELECT 
activity_title
, SUM (message_segments) AS "cumulative_message_segments"
FROM textbankvendor.messages_export
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 1
```

However when trying to get activity_published_at as a variable I run into error messages. The following query gives (and several variations/adjustments of trial and error) give an error message:

```
SELECT 
activity_title
, SUM (message_segments) AS "cumulative_message_segments"
, activity_published_at
FROM textbankvendor.messages_export
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 1
```

Status: Failed

Error in SQL: column "messages_export.activity_published_at" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

Is there a way to successfully query this intended result?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0):

All the columns that do not appear in the GROUPBY list MUST be aggregated in some way. You have two options with the table above:

1. Preserving the same group by function and take any value for the timestamp (provided they are unique per activity title)

```
SELECT 
activity_title
, SUM (message_segments) AS "cumulative_message_segments"
, ANY_VALUE(activity_published_at) as activity_published_at
FROM textbankvendor.messages_export
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 1
```

2. Put directly the timestamp into the group by columns

```
SELECT 
activity_title
, activity_published_at
, SUM (message_segments) AS "cumulative_message_segments"
FROM textbankvendor.messages_export
GROUP BY 1, 2
ORDER BY 1
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want one row per activity title, I would suggest:

```
SELECT activity_title,
       SUM(message_segments) AS cumulative_message_segments,
       MIN(activity_published_at) as activity_published_at
FROM textbankvendor.messages_export
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 1;
```

The problem with your query is that the `SELECT` columns are inconsistent with the `GROUP BY` columns.